# Instantiate string[] field

Tags: c#, string, properties

I'm working on a console application which also had reference to class library. In class library i have following code.

```
namespace SomeClass  
{  
    public class ClassOne  
    {  
        public string[] SupportedFiles;  
    }  
}
```

And in console app, program.cs, i'm trying to assign SupportedFiles.

```
class Program  
    {  
        public ClassOne class1 { get; set; }  
        public Program()  
        {  
            class1.SupportedFiles = new string[] { "Test", "Test" };
           //class1.SupportedFiles[0] = "First";
           //class1.SupportedFiles[1] = "Second"; 
        }  
    }
```

But the line `class1.SupportedFiles = new string[] { "Test", "Test" };` throws

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.'

What am i missing? Am I so dumb instantiating a string array. Please help me out.

Comment: You have defined `SupportedFiles` and accessing  `SupportedArchitectures`

Comment: Actually, if you want know, this is a duplicate question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: This question has been asked for numerous times and [duplicated] for numerous time

Answer (score 1):

You are missing instance of class where `string[]` is present

Try with this before accessing `string[]`

```
ClassOne cOne = new ClassOne();
```

Do not miss adding reference of your class library to project where you want to access this string and also include namespace in `program.cs` file

This can be your working solution:

```
using SomeClass;
class Program  
    {  
        //Not required to create property of ClassOne
        //public ClassOne class1 { get; set; }  
        public Program()  
        {  
           //In this way, you can create instance of class.
           ClassOne class1 = new ClassOne();
           //Now with the help of instance of class, you can access all public properties of that class
            class1.SupportedFiles= new string[] { "Test", "Test" };
           //class1.SupportedFiles[0] = "First";
           //class1.SupportedFiles[1] = "Second"; 
        }  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize your object before accessing its members. For that you have several(basic) options:

```
class Program  
{  
    public ClassOne Class1 { get; set; }  
    public Program()  
    {  
        Class1 = new ClassOne();
        Class1.SupportedFiles= new string[] { "Test", "Test" };
    }  
}
```

or even better:

```
class Program  
{  
    public ClassOne Class1 { get; set; }  
    public Program()  
    {  
        Class1 = new ClassOne()
        {
            SupportedFiles = new string[] { "Test", "Test" }
        };
       //class1.SupportedFiles[0] = "First";
       //class1.SupportedFiles[1] = "Second"; 
    }  
}
```

or if you're using `C#6` and above, you have such thing as auto-property initializers:

```
class Program  
{  
    public ClassOne Class1 { get; set; } = new ClassOne();
    public Program()  
    {  
        Class1.SupportedFiles= new string[] { "Test", "Test" };
       //class1.SupportedFiles[0] = "First";
       //class1.SupportedFiles[1] = "Second"; 
    }  
}
```

Comment: Still ClassOne doesn't have the property `SupportedArchitectures` see updates in the question..! lol